# An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json

Tags: php, json, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm using PostgreSQL with Symfony.

I have a user table which is as below:

```
id | email         | roles
---------------------------------------
1  | abc@gmail.com | ["ROLE_IVM_USER"]
```

The roles column is JSON type as shown above.

I want to get user list which has role of `ROLE_IVM_USER` using code below:

```
$queryBuilder
            ->andWhere(sprintf('%s.roles IN (:roles)', $rootAlias))
            ->setParameter('roles', [User::ROLE_IVM_USER]);
```

which results in the below error:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json = unknown\nLINE 1: ... u0_ WHERE u0_.organization_id = $1 AND u0_.roles IN ($2) OR...\n ^\nHINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."
```

**I'm new to PostgreSQL let me know how to get users with the role of `ROLE_IVM_USER`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I achived the desired result without using any third party lib:

```
$rsm = $this->createResultSetMappingBuilder('u');

        $rawQuery = sprintf(
            'SELECT %s
                    FROM public.user u
                    WHERE u.roles::jsonb ?? :role',
            $rsm->generateSelectClause()
        );

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($rawQuery, $rsm);
        $query->setParameter('role', $role);
        return $query->getResult();
```

Hope this will help someone and will save hours of investigation

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `LIKE` instead of an `IN` :

```php
$queryBuilder
  ->andWhere(sprintf('%s.roles LIKE :roles', $rootAlias))
  ->setParameter('roles', '%' . User::ROLE_IVM_USER . '%');
```

Comment: tried and resulted in `An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown`

Comment: And with this : `"$rootAlias.roles LIKE :roles"` instead of using sprintf ? And it's all the query or there is other thing in your QB that could cause this problem ?

Comment: didn't work either. no there is nothing else.. the issue is due to PostgreSQL as it has different syntax for the JSON column

Comment: Did you see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388433/doctrine-search-in-json-array