# Filter Json Postgres column using Sqlalchemy in flask (after type cast from String to Json)

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a column in which data has stored as a String but i am converting that column to Json when retrieving data. after casting string to Json i want to filter that Json using mobile_number. Can any one help me to do it ?

```
db = Sqlalchemy()
query = db.session.query(table1).filter(db.cast(table1.string_data,db.JSON))
```

I want to add filter to json something like this

```
query = db.session.query(table1).filter(db.cast(table1.string_data,db.JSON)['mobile_number'] == "123456789")
```

I am getting error when trying this. can anyone suggest me another method ?

Comment: I would first check if the casting worked as you wanted, and then read more on [sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON) to see if you need to do a casting of the value as well with `astext` or `astext.cast(...)`.

Comment: @van i am able to type cast column from string to json but unable to filter that json

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @van ProgrammingError("(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: json = unknown  .........btw thanks for the reply

Comment: I think you still need to cast the values to the type (string or number) in order to compare, as one cannot compare two json values. @see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32843380/99594.