# PostgreSQL, how to add filter on JSON type

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a query and its OK:

```
SELECT  tableA.id
       ,json_elements.each_section -> 'id'    AS parameter_name
       ,json_elements.each_section -> 'value' AS parameter_value
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  tableA.id                                          AS id
           ,JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(tableA.operation_values::JSON) AS each_section
    FROM tableA
) json_elements
ON tableA.id = json_elements.id
```

but, if I try to add filter:

```
SELECT  tableA.id
       ,json_elements.each_section -> 'id'    AS parameter_name
       ,json_elements.each_section -> 'value' AS parameter_value
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  tableA.id                                          AS id
           ,JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(tableA.operation_values::JSON) AS each_section
    FROM tableA
) json_elements
ON tableA.id = json_elements.id
WHERE (json_elements.each_section -> 'id') = 'exam'
```

I have an error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: json = unknown
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

if I cast:

```
SELECT  tableA.id
       ,json_elements.each_section -> 'id'    AS parameter_name
       ,json_elements.each_section -> 'value' AS parameter_value
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  tableA.id                                          AS id
           ,JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(tableA.operation_values::JSON) AS each_section
    FROM tableA
) json_elements
ON tableA.id = json_elements.id
WHERE (json_elements.each_section -> 'id') = to_json('exam'::text)
```

I get:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: json = json
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Do u know how to add working filter?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here [Operator does not exist: json = json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843213/operator-does-not-exist-json-json)

I just cast to ::text my filter:

WHERE (json_elements.each_section -> 'id')::text = 'exam'

Comment: You should cast it to `jsonb` - which is the recommended data type to store JSON anyway